# Concerning the Firebug debugging Tool - Is It Obsolete?

Tags: firefox

Many probably have the same generic question regarding the Firebug debugging tool these days. Now that Mozilla has reached Firefox 51, is Firebug now considered obsolete? Obviously, the Firefox development tools now available in the Web Console can perform pretty much the same functions.
. . .
Does the Firefox 51 Debugger now also feature the same 'Breakpoint on Property Change' capability that Firebug has, or something similar? If so, why use Firebug at all?
. . .
Just wondering, and thanks for any info.

Comment: I have some issues with this Tool, thanks to this post I am close to finding a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Firebug is no longer being maintained because it would have been very complicated to make it compatible to Firefox's new e10s multi-process architecture and some other reasons. Most of the features have been integrated in Firefox developer tools and work as good (and some even better, meaning faster / more functionality / better design) now.
If you miss any features that were available in Firebug, feel free to file new [bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools).
For further reference, see [hacks.mozilla.org](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/10/firebug-devtools-integration/) or [getfirebug.com](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/02/08/merging-firebug-into-the-built-in-firefox-developer-tools/)

Comment: Most interesting; I think this is what most of us have assumed - and thanks immensely for taking the time to respond. This brings up yet another question that many must also have pondered. How long has this been the case? Surely this has been true since Firefox 50. Has this been widely publicized? I don't mean just by Mozilla.

Comment: It is diffucult to say, because it was a long process. Also, it is still possible to use Firebug, so I can't tell you a specific date. Back in 2014, the Firebug team decided to [work together with the Fx DevTools](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1047248#c0). I think the final decision to stop maintaining Firebug was publicy announced with the articles I mentioned above. Some IT news reported about this, but I think mostly only web developers or people reading Mozilla news knew about it at that time. Now, there are notes in the addon description and on their website.

Comment: Yes, I noticed as much, but since I didn't use Firebug very often, it's not something I followed. Like you say, I think mostly just developers directly interested kept up with it. I do know, however, how popular Firebug is in general, and also the great popularity of Firefox DevTools (although, certainly now, whether it's Edge, Chrome or even Brave, they're all very similar these days). Given the popularity of Firefox and Firebug, one would have thought that it would have been more broadly publicized. Anyway, no matter these days. Thanks much for the info.